# How to pick query data out of an object that can be of multiple types?

Tags: typescript, graphql

I'm trying to run either a `projectQuery` or `itemQuery` hook that returns either `{ projects }` or `{ items }` respectively in a variable called `data`. When I look at the type of `data` with Typescript, it shows up as `ProjectsQuery | ItemsQuery` which is correct.

```
  const isProject = type === RootTypes.ProjectType;
  const { loading, error, data } = isProject ? useProjectsQuery({}) : useItemsQuery({});
  const { projects, items } = data || {};
  const thingList = isProject ? projects : items;
```

How can I selectively pull either `projects` or `items` out of my data object while preserving the type? The TypeScript error I get with the code below is that the `ProjectsQuery` type does not have `items` and vice versa, which is obviously correct. Is there an elegant way to handle this? The way that I was shying away from was running the query for both and then selecting which data I'd use based on the `isProject` enum.

I know one elegant way is to do type-checking like this:

```
export const isProject = (thing: Project | Item): thing is Project => {
  return (thing as Project).__typename === 'Project';
};
```

but the problem is that I need to have the object to actually run this function on it and I'm using an enum to determine what type I have so I only have the object within the `data` object and that's exactly what I'm trying to extract out of it.

Comment: A little irrelevant to the question, but ... is this code written in React? If so you shouldn't put hooks in conditionals (https://flaviocopes.com/react-hooks-conditionals/)

Comment: Why you don't just do `const thingList = data`

Comment: @antoniom Fascinating, it is react and you are right that I've read and experienced that you can't put them in conditionals but this seems to work great. I wonder if it helps that both hooks in the conditional use useQuery under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React hooks can't be called conditionally but you can use `skip` option to choose query hook:

```
const isProject = type === RootTypes.ProjectType;
const { loading, error, data } = useProjectsQuery({ skip: !isProject });
const { loading:loadingItems, error: errorItems, data:dataItems } = useItemsQuery({ skip: isProject });
if(loading || loadingItem) return <Loading />;
const thingList = isProject ? data.projects : dataItems.items;
```

where `thingList` [probably] will be an array of union type elements.

... but it's not an optimal solution, what about different components (`<ProjectsLoader/>`/`<ItemsLoader>`) to query each type? Components are a cheap abstraction in react. Deeper elements/children will still need a different treatment [?].